# Acceleration to Velocity to Displacement

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm working on an application that needs to determine human activity, using accelerometer and gyroscope, or one of this devices.

I'm defining the acceleration using sensors of my phone. Then I'm using this type of integration to get the velocity and displacement .:
[image]

This means that I'm taking the 1st value of acceleration , multiplying by the next value , dividing by 2 and multiplying by the time between measurements. So I get the trapezia, which defines the velocity during the moment of time. Then I'm adding all the trapezia to receive the velocity. Same with Displacement, but this method is terrible. But this is not all...

### Accelerometer makes unpredictable output!

**Phone goes up and down**

[image]

**Phone goes Down and up**

[image]

The questions:

1. Is there any way to avoid huge error of integration ?
2. Is there another way to get velocity from acceleration ?
3. Is my accelerometer data right (phone goes up or down, how can I determine this)?
4. How can I be sure about it's output (can I check it somehow)?

Comment: instead of multiplying shouldn't  you add those two values?

Comment: @pskink That was a mistake in that picture , i'm adding those values =)

Comment: " This mean that i'm taking 1st value of acceleration , multiplying by the next
value , dividing by 2 and multiplyaing by the time between measurements." is it a mistake as well? seems that your velocity is always positive

Comment: @pskink. No ofcourse. When the acc is negative i have :
`((neg-neg2)/2)*Ts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Kalman filtering. See for e.g.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter